# Xamarin build pipeline (ios-android) azuredevops multienvironment

Tags: xamarin, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to build and deploy a Xamarin app in both iOS and Android.
Release in stages to 3 environments (Dev-UAT-Production)

When in release it will distribute to appcenter.

I have added a step in the pipeline before the build takes place to change the value
of a constant in class that defines what kind of build I am doing EG "Dev" or "Production" etc..

however I cannot find a way in the release pipeline to have some sort of condition

1. if(Dev) execute DevStage
2. if(UAT) execute  UAT Stage
3. if(Production) execute  Production Stage

If the above is not possible I would have to 3 pipelines one of each stage.

Any ideas -link how to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not possible** to achieve it because **your constant in your code will not be read before you execute your stage.** The code can be read only after you execute your stage.

Comment: So how would you do it? Or how do people do it

Comment: The code can only be read when the stage is ongoing, But at that point, it won't be possible for choosing which stage to be executed. You would have to have 3 pipelines of each stage. @developer9969